# How do you add the same images of different pixel densities to the drawable directory (android studio)?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am following the tutorials in the Big Nerd Ranch book for android but that book is structured for Eclipse + ADT.

I am trying to add an arrow icon to a button and I have folders (drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi) that contain sets of identical images. Ideally I would like these folders to appear in the drawable folder but whether I copy and paste or drag these folders it doesn't seem to work. They appear in the packages section instead, but when this happens I can't seem to reference them from xml files in the layout folder.

The best I can do is drag/copy the files (not the folder)into the drawable folder, in which case they stay there and I am able to use them. The problem with this is I can have, at most, one pixel density for the set of images that is in there. The only way I can think of is if I change the names of all of them so that the problem of overwriting is gone.

However in the mipmap folder in the ic_laucher.png folder there are four files of the same name, except there are greyed out density descriptions beside them. How is this done?

What should I do?

[image: Trying to add these three files]

[image]

As you can see I have now added the images using the file system. I am still unable to reference these using the resource name however. I am still not sure why.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31210838/different-sized-images-with-the-same-name-in-one-drawable-folder/31210996#31210996

Comment: Good question. You can of course place the files into the right drawable-xy folders via the filesystem, but I agree with you that it's a rather strange how Android studio shows the drawables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing in the mipmap "folder" is just some UI magic. The Android project view in Android studio will combine all resources with the same name into a single entry like you are seeing for `ic_launcher.png` to make it easier to view your resources.

Behind the scenes, this still uses different folders on disk. If you open up your project in Windows Explorer, you will see separate folders for `mipmap-xhdpi`, `mipmap-mdpi`, etc.

The same is true for your drawable folders. You still want to keep your images in separate density-specific folders on disk. Android Studio will then display them to you as if they were all in the same `drawable` folder in the Android project view. You cannot physically move your density specific folders beneath the `drawable` folder.

Comment: Alright then but I have also tried adding the folders to drawable in the Package view like the book says. Whilst this works (I am able to add the sub-directories with the different densities) I am then unable to reference them with xml. e.g. android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_right" becomes highlighted in red. But when I drag the files directly into drawable in the Android view I am then able to reference them, but I just can't have all of the densities in there at once.

Comment: I typically don't manipulate my PNG drawables in Android Studio. I would look at these folders in Windows Explorer to verify that they are in the correct location there first. Alternatively, you can switch to the "Project" view instead of the "Android" view at the top of the project pane in Studio, and then you can see the individual folders instead of the collapsed view.

Comment: Okay I decided I'd use the file system too. I have added all the files I require into drawable. How do I now access them. I'll add an image to this post but the problem is it is like these files don't exist as I am not able to reference them in xml.

Comment: Okay I have figured out how to do it now. The file system does indeed help. Instead of putting the folders into the drawable folder just put them into the res folder and the "drawable-" will sort them in the Android Studio and they will like sub-directories of drawable.